# Best place to start learning Stereophotogrammetry

Tags: model, 3d

Firstly I would like to achieve a final goal as can be found in the links below:

[Link 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixkQumdlQ-0)
[Link 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3toTkQ3DPVs)

Now I started doing a little bit of research and found that Stereophotogrammetry is the field I should be looking to study should I want to achieve the desired result in the links above. Now I know there is software like Catch 123d that can help me do this but I would like to write an application hat takes images ad constructs the 3d model. Now is Stereophotogrammetry the right place to start looking to study and if so can anyone recommend where to begin to start learning this as I have googled but nothing constructive pops up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is known as 3D reconstruction.  I don't know if there is anything better in the bookstores these days but [Multiple-view geometry by Hartley and Zisserman](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/) is a good textbook on the subject.